# C# How to get a span of a div class?

Tags: c#, html, parsing

I want to create an application, that searches for a specific keyword and shows a definition of the keyword. I am using a web browser, that's navigating to the website. Now I want to parse that HTML-Code and get the `<span>` with the description. Is that possible? I am not able to solve this problem.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="_G1d _wle _xle">
    <div class="_RBg">
        <div class="mod" data-md="50" style="clear:none" data-ved="0ahUKEwjL6Nn40YzRAhWBeFAKHW6qAOwQkCkIrQEoATAV">
            <!--m-->
            <div class="_cgc" data-hveid="174" data-ved="0ahUKEwjL6Nn40YzRAhWBeFAKHW6qAOwQziAIrgEoADAV">
                <div jsl="$t t-oF0h478wPRI;$x 0;" class="r-iv2Iqojxo_88">
                    <div class="kno-rdesc r-ia8pb7p3eFsA" jsl="$t t-JgTEvN6zUII;$x 0;">
                    <span>
                        "The Eiffel Tower is a wrought iron lattice tower on the Champ de Mars in Paris, France. It is named after the engineer Gustave Eiffel, whose company designed and built the tower."
                    </span>
                    <span>...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--n-->
</div>
```

And that's my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=" + textBox1.Text);
    Get_Data();
}

private void Get_Data()
{
    foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "_cgc")
        {
            description.Text = el.InnerText;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code as code instead of a screenshot.

Comment: That's my fault sorry. I am new on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `Split` to get the span :

```
    private void Get_Data()
    {
        foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
        {
            if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "_cgc")
            {
                string[] splitSpan = el.InnerText.Split(new[] { "<span>", "</span>" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                description.Text = splitSpan[1];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is always a unhandled exception of type "System.NummReferenceException". It seems to me that the problem is located at "webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div")".

Comment: I solved the old problem, but now there is a new one. See yourself: http://i.imgur.com/IRpZ7cj.png